# Bootstrap 4 unable to pull col to right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6

I have three columns displayed in one row, I need to swap the first column with the last column while in md but not while in sm/xs.

I want it to view like this in desktop mode:

```
[C][B][A]
```

and like this in mobile view:

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
```

I tried this:

```
<div class="row pt-2">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 float-md-right">
        <img src="assets/img/3-delivery.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <img src="assets/img/arrow.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 float-md-left">
      <img src="assets/img/4-served.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `push` `pull` classes..

http://www.codeply.com/go/DhuRlsA6U4

```
<div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 push-md-8">
            a
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            b
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 pull-md-8">
            c
        </div>
</div>
```